# Python nested list slicing

Tags: python, list, slice

My list:

```
>>> l = [["A", "A1", 1, 2, 3], 
         ["B", "A2", 4, 5, 6], 
         ["C", "A3", 7, 8, 9], 
         ["D", "A4", 10, 11, 12]]
```

Slicing operation:

```
>>> [[n[0] for n in l], [u[1:] for u in l]]
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
  [['A1', 1, 2, 3], 
  ['A2', 4, 5, 6], 
  ['A3', 7, 8, 9], 
  ['A4', 10, 11, 12]]]
```

Is any way to slice this list without extra square brackets? like below:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
 ['A1', 1, 2, 3], 
 ['A2', 4, 5, 6], 
 ['A3', 7, 8, 9], 
 ['A4', 10, 11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate the lists:

```
>>> [[n[0] for n in l]] + [u[1:] for u in l]
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A1', 1, 2, 3], ['A2', 4, 5, 6], ['A3', 7, 8, 9], ['A4', 10, 11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create another list and join the result like this

```
print [[n[0] for n in l]] + [u[1:] for u in l]
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
>>> mylist = [[n[0] for n in l]] + [u[1:] for u in l]
>>> mylist
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A1', 1, 2, 3], ['A2', 4, 5, 6], ['A3', 7, 8, 9], ['A4', 10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: Never name your variables as `list`